# Reflection for getting test status in Specflow 2.3.1 not working

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow

When I try to getProperty of TestStatus in specflow 2.3.1, it is not working. Any workaround for this?

> Error = System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Bascially, pInfo = null

```
PropertyInfo pInfo = typeof(ScenarioContext).GetProperty("TestStatus", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
MethodInfo getter = pInfo.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);object TestResult = getter.Invoke(ScenarioContext.Current, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error is, that we changed the internals of that class.

The change was, that we made the TestStatus public (and renamed it).

You can access it now via the public property ScenarioExecutionStatus (https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/TechTalk.SpecFlow/ScenarioContext.cs#L54)

Answer (score 0):

With new version below code is working implemented in our code

```
PropertyInfo pInfo = typeof(ScenarioContext).GetProperty("ScenarioExecutionStatus", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
MethodInfo getter = pInfo.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);
object TestResult = getter.Invoke(ScenarioContext.Current, null);
```